# Convert Code LAtex to image

Tags: mathjax

How can I convert Latex code to an image when I post it on the website?
Demo: https://giainhanh.vn/question/4L81Kj4

Comment: you have tagged this as mathjax, using mathjax is usually preferable to making an image as the math is then still text see for example any of the posts at [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/397572/an-identity-for-the-elliptic-theta-function)

Comment: i want to use math-honeycomb latex to convert the code to png.latex rendering in README.md on Github